# bootstrap nth:child css property not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i have bunch of cards over here i just want that each first and third card in the row gets margin top of 50px but it is not working with bootstrap but using css it is working?is there any class in bootstrap through which i can do this? i know i can do it manually by doing .mt class but i have a php code which dynamically generate this so it fails over there please have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/shubham-ghuge/pen/xxOzeJp) and help me with this.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, hic.</div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, hic.</div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, hic.</div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, hic.</div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, hic.</div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, hic.</div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, hic.</div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, hic.</div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, hic.</div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
.card{
margin:30px 20px;
padding:20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please add your code in the question. A link to a longer version of your code is fine as an extra but the main issue with your code should be on SO in case your link dies.

Comment: i have fixed the code with the solution dont worry about the link i won't do any changes in that codepen i am a newbie here will make sure to add actual code in next questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.card` is a child of `col-sm-4` so you have to add CSS like below

```
.col-sm-4:nth-child(odd) .card{
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  background: red;
}
```